# simplecursoradapter, list activity with button

Tags: android, button, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

i want to design my interface like this :

[image]

and i try my code, show interface look like this:

[image]

i want to make design, any button in top and listview in bottom of button, how ? with listactivity.

i have file Datalist.java like this :

```
public class DataList extends ListActivity{
 private ListView conListView;
 private CursorAdapter conAdapter;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        conListView=getListView();
        conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

        // map each name to a TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "nama" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dataTextView};
        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DataList.this, R.layout.data_list, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
    }
}
```

and have data_list.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dataTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for advance.

Comment: First see this :- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ListView in an Activity instead of a ListActivity. A ListActivity is an activity which only contains a List. Some example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button ... />
    <ListView ... android:layout_belowTo="@id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```